# How to solve the error ocured while using a simulation software Wien2K?

Tags: linux, perl

I am getting the following error while running a simulation software working with DFT called Wien2k in my ubuntu. As i understood its about missing a module, if so any body help me to install it.

```
Error - Missing Header
Can't locate CGI.pm in @INC (you may need to install the CGI module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30 /usr/share/perl/5.30 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /home/narayanan/WIEN2k_19.2/SRC_w2web/htdocs/util/upload2.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/narayanan/WIEN2k_19.2/SRC_w2web/htdocs/util/upload2.pl line 3.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sudo apt install libcgi-pm-perl
```

I am not quite sure which CGI.pm exactly is needed, but if the above does not work, try some from here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=cgi.pm